# MVC - How to deserialize a Dictionary without having brackets [0] added to the key?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

my deserialize Dictionary's key results in "brand[0]" when I send in "brand" to the api.

I have a class like this:

```
public class SearchRequest
{
    public bool Html { get; set; } = false;
    public Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> Tags { get; set; }
}

// MVC Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SearchRequest searchRequest)
{
    ...
}
```

And a json request like this that I post to the controller:

```
{
  "html": true,
  "tags": {
    "brand": [
      "bareminerals"
    ]
  }
}
```

The binding seams to work and the searchRequest object is created but the resulting dictionary dose not have the key "**brand**" in it but insted the key "**brand[0]**" how can I preserve the real values I send in?

**Edit:** I need tags to be able to contain multiple tags, with multiple options, this was a simpel example.

[image]

Comment: `HashSet<string>` is a collection class, so it serializes to a JSON array. Change your dictionary to `Dictionary<string, string>` if there's only one value per key.

Comment: Please use a debbuger. You will see that you have a key "brand", if you get "brand" key, then you will get HashSet. To access element in set you can use index operator [0].

Comment: Hostel: No, this is not the case, the key itself is a string containing the [0].
itsme86: I need multiple values

Comment: can you show us the calling code?

Comment: the calling code is a postman json post with that exakt body

Comment: It looks like what you've shown us is all downstream from where the key value gets serialized into "brand[0]".

Comment: the MVC Controller is handling this for me, don't know if I can set a bp erlier?

Comment: Why is your Tags property not just some normal POCO with a `public string[] Brand` property?

Comment: Caius Jard: Tags contains of a dynamic set of tag/values. Its represent elastic search facets. brand is just one of hundreds

Comment: The json you showed would not deserialize into a key value with "brand[0]" Do you have the actual value that you've used to test?

Comment: It dose when it goes over mvc controller, but not a jsonConvert am working on a fiddle

Comment: You're using the JSON you posted and putting it in POSTMAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One soulution to my problem is to create a custom model bind, so this is what am using now, but I dont understand why I need to, and I feel like there should be a easyer way? But am gonna leve It here anyhow.

```
public class FromJsonBodyAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
    {
        return new JsonModelBinder();
    }

    private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var stream = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var checkoutOrderDataStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(checkoutOrderDataStr, bindingContext.ModelType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is going on with your setup.  You should not need a custom binder. I still think the problem is most likely with your calling code - whatever you're using as a client.

I'm using Asp.net Core 3.1. Here's what I threw together as a quick test.

Created Asp.net Core web application template with MVC.  I declared two classes - a request POCO and a result POCO. The request was your class:

```
public class SearchRequest
{
    public bool Html { get; set; } = false;
    public Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The result was the same thing with a datetime field added just for the heck of it:

```
public class SearchResult : SearchRequest
{
    public SearchResult(SearchRequest r)
    {
        this.Html = r.Html;
        this.Tags = r.Tags;
    }

    public DateTime RequestedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I Added a simple post method on the default HomeController.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody] SearchRequest searchRequest)
    {
        return new ObjectResult(new SearchResult(searchRequest));
    }
```

I added a console Application to the solution to act as a client.  I copied the two class definitions into that project.

I added this as the main method.  Note you can either have the camel casing options on the request or not - asp.net accepted either.

```
    static async Task Main(string[] _)
    {
        var tags = new[] { new { k = "brand", tags = new string[] { "bareminerals" } } }
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.k, v => new HashSet<string>(v.tags));

        var request = new SearchRequest() { Html = true, Tags = tags };

        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase };

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request, options);

        Console.WriteLine(json);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:59276", content);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SearchResult>(data, options);

            Console.WriteLine(data);

            var keysSame = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(request.Tags.Keys, result.Tags.Keys);
            var valuesSame = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(request.Tags.Values.SelectMany(x => x),
                                                      result.Tags.Values.SelectMany(x=>x));

            Console.WriteLine($"Keys: {keysSame} Values: {valuesSame}");
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

{"html":true,"tags":{"brand":["bareminerals"]}}

{"requestedAt":"2020-10-30T19:22:17.8525982-04:00","html":true,"tags":{"brand":["bareminerals"]}}

Keys: True Values: True

Comment: Thanks you for helping! I tryed your client and got the same result in my codebase (we are not using core) I Dont now whats up it it, but is huge and old, so it must be some legay code hiding. The so i need to stick with the custom binder it seams.

Thans again!